# How to make meSpeak.js read special characters?

Tags: javascript, espeak

I would like to use [mespeak.js script](http://www.masswerk.at/mespeak/) (based on speak.js based on espeak) for text-to-speech - which has a czech voice file -, but for some reason it skips czech special characters like ě, š, č, ř, ž and reads only the rest.

As espeak on Windows reads them correctly, I tried to compile a new voice file (cs.json), but the problem persists.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what those characters sound like, but your best bet might be to try to approximate the closest english sounding character combination.

For instance, if š sounds like **sh** in English (not saying it does) then just replace all instances of š with sh.

Comment: yes I could do this before sending them to the script, but I would find it more clean to edit the script - in fact they sound differently on different occasions, which is already taken into account in the dictionary and works locally with espeak.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a better way to use this e-speak modification instead of mespeak:
http://eeejay.github.io/espeak/emscripten/espeak.html (demo)